# Javascript Error when uploading image TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I'm following the getting started documentation guide from [this page](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/get-started/upload-images/). It is supposed to work like [this demo](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/local-upload/).

I implemented it with this code:

```
$(".answers-list .answer textarea, textarea.soal").tinymce({
    images_upload_url: 'uploadimage.php',
    theme: "modern",
    plugins: [
        "eqneditor advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste" 
    ],
    toolbar: "undo redo | eqneditor link image | styleselect | bold italic | bullist numlist outdent indent ",
});
```

When I try to upload the image, the javascript console gives error like:

```
tinymce.min.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: b(...).createObjectURL is not a function
    at Object.c [as createObjectURL] (tinymce.min.js:12)
    at g (tinymce.min.js:12)
    at Object.f [as create] (tinymce.min.js:12)
    at b.h (plugin.min.js:1)
    at b.e [as fire] (tinymce.min.js:7)
    at b.fire (tinymce.min.js:7)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (tinymce.min.js:16)
    at a (tinymce.min.js:2)
    at HTMLInputElement.p (tinymce.min.js:2)
```

It doesn't even start to process the upload. What's wrong with the code?

Comment: What version of TinyMCE are you using?

Comment: @MichaelFromin I'm using 4.6.7 (2017-09-18)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. My solution was to rename the custom global varname URL to something different like WEBSITE_URL.

I think that TinyMCE is using URL as global varname too.

Answer (score 0):

I think @rjgamer is right. The only way I could fix this was:

```
window.native_url = URL;

$(window).on("load", function() {
  // after tinymce script is loaded 
  URL.createObjectURL = native_url.createObjectURL;
});
```

its bad but it works.